# Find if services are enabled in Java

Tags: java, windows

is there a way in Java to find if services like Windows Defender, IIS, Telnet are enabled? I am aware of the system class and you could always test ports with the socket class but I am looking for an easier solution. (If there is one)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: No not a way to start or stop them. Check if they are enabled:

Comment: For example if(telnet.isEnabled) { do something}

Comment: I don't know what that means. Services do not have an enabled/disabled state.

Comment: take Remote Desktop for example, it can be either enabled or disabled. I might have used the wrong terminology when I said service. Feature is a better word

Comment: Your terminology is too vague. You have tell us exactly what feature/service/etc you are talking about. Do you mean roles/features on a windows server?